# How to generate .map file from from .shp files?

Tags: shapefile, esri, mapserver

I have a bunch of ESRI Shape files (.shp) bundled with .dbf and .shx files.
Is there anyway to generate .map file consumable by MapServer automatically?

Ideally by some command-line command in linux.

Comment: have you found anything?

Answer (score 3):

[Quantum GIS](http://qgis.org/) has a plugin called **MapServer Export**. Append all your ShapeFiles to the QGIS, set layers styles, order and other properties as you would like to see them and use the MapServer Export plugin. After some simple parameters setting you will get the .map file. Quantum GIS has a Python API so it is possible to write a script to do this automatically...